app/Http/Controllers/Admin/TicketController.php on line 17

app/Http/Controllers/Admin/TicketController.php on line 17
ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Admin\TicketController::tickets(), 1 passed in

  public function tickets($type = '',Request $request){
        $arr = [
            'Seller Request',
            'I want to become a seller',
            'seller request',
            'Seller request',
        ];
        if ($request->word){
            $tickets = Ticket::where('id',trim($request->word))->orderByDesc('id')->paginate(100);
            return view('admin.layouts.tickets.index',compact('tickets'));
        }
        switch ($type){
            case '':
                $tickets = Ticket::where('status','1')->where('from_support',null)->whereNotIn('title',$arr)->orderByDesc('id')->paginate(100);
                break;
            case 'Seller Request':
                $tickets = Ticket::where('status','1')->whereIn('title',$arr)->orderByDesc('id')->paginate(100);
                break;
            case 'from support':
                $tickets = Ticket::where('status','1')->where('from_support','1')->orderByDesc('id')->paginate(100);
                break;


        }
        return view('admin.layouts.tickets.index',compact('tickets'));
    }

    Route::get('tickets/{type?}','TicketController@tickets')->name('admin-tickets');

A problem I don't know how to solve

Dependency injections must be listed as first parameters, followed by the rest.
Change the method definition to tickets(Request $request, $type = '')

Why is your title a filename and line. Please change this to a short description of the question...

Route::get('tickets','TicketController@tickets')->name('admin-tickets')


public function tickets(Request $request){ 
     $type = $request->type;
}



/tickets?type=

You can validate the ticket query parameter using request object in controller's ticket method.

Why would you change the route parameter to a query parameter???
